# Regex to select last folder in UNC

Tags: regex, powershell

I need to extract always the last folder of UNC paths :

```
\\server\folder\subfolder (I want "subfolder")
\\server\folder\sub-folder (I want "sub-folder")
\\server\folder\subfolder$ (I want "subfolder$")
\\server\folder\sub folder (I want "sub folder")
```

I am trying with regex but I can't find a solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this: `'(?:.*?)\\([^\\]*)$'`:

Example:

```
@"
\\server\folder\subfolder (I want "subfolder")
\\server\folder\sub-folder (I want "sub-folder")
\\server\folder\subfolder$ (I want "subfolder$")
\\server\folder\sub folder (I want "sub folder")
"@ -split [environment]::NewLine | % { $_ -replace '(?:.*?)\\([^\\]*)$', '$1' }

subfolder (I want "subfolder")
sub-folder (I want "sub-folder")
subfolder$ (I want "subfolder$")
sub folder (I want "sub folder")
```

Comment: Great, it works perfect! Btw, maybe there is an easier solution with "split" (last)?

Comment: @expirat001 take a look at my answer.

Comment: I would avoid split, because it creates objects + arrays = time wasted. The cleanest solution is to use the DirectoryInfo class that @CB have shown you, but you wanted regex, so you got it :)

Answer (score 3):

Using .net you can avoid regex:

```
([system.io.directoryinfo]"\\server\folder\subfolder").BaseName
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

**Input.txt**:

```
\\server\folder\subfolder
\\server\folder\sub-folder
\\server\folder\subfolder$
\\server\folder\sub folder
```

With this Powershell

**test.ps1**:

```
$input_path = "input.txt"
$output_file = "output.txt"
$regex = "([^\\]+)$"
select-string -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value } > $output_file
```

**output.txt**:

```
subfolder
sub-folder
subfolder$
sub folder
```